# How to list all types inherited from a specific type in a solution?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to get a list of all types in a VS solution that are inherited from a specific type. 
Below code seems to list all classes in a vs solution, but not sure how to filter them by inhertance:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken);
var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path, cancellationToken);
Project project = solution.Projects.First(p => p.Name == "WebApplication1");
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

var classes = compilation.
    GlobalNamespace.
    GetNamespaceMembers().
    SelectMany(x => x.GetMembers());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`SymbolFinder.FindDerivedClassesAsync()`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/84bc7eea2e05e9d9d7e1b53c2a107c0ac9857a72/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder_Hierarchy.cs#L178).

Using your example it would look something like:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken);
var solution = await workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(path, cancellationToken);

INamedTypeSymbol symbol = ... //Find the symbol for the type you're interested interested
var results = await SymbolFinder.FindDerivedClassesAsync(symbol, solution);
```

Note that while this example is for classes, the `SymbolFinder` has methods for a variety of scenarios including finding implementations of interfaces.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Josh, you nailed this question so fast. What are the good resources I should know about Roslyn? Google search does not help much since searches usually land on the Roslyn's source repository, not very helpful. Any good book you recommend? Thank again.

Comment: There's not much documentation unfortunately, but I wrote some blog posts about Roslyn while I was learning it: https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/learn-roslyn-now/

Comment: That is nice set of articles. Thank you!